# Decode a H.264 frame from a buffer android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, decode

I am sending h264 encoded frames from PC and receiving them inside android NDK. The android client receives the frame and stores it into a buffer. Buffer keeps updating as it receives the frame. (The code is not written by me)

My question is that how can I decode(I mainly need help with this) & render(openGL?) the frame from a buffer that is inside ndk. Can someone please provide some kind of sample code/library etc? I don't have prior experience with decoding/encoding.

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of ffmpeg? Its open source.

Comment: I have but I cannot seem to find a tutorial/guide etc.It is just code snippets  from other people.